# Issue with front-end ajax, getting a 302 redirect when accessing wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Tags: ajax, user-roles, user-access

I want to use wp ajax for frontend logged in user but showing error of 302 Found and call home page.
it is working fine for admin users and non logged in users.

here is network log screenshot:

[image]

i have used both ajax function like below:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_sale', 'add_sale');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_sale', 'add_sale');
```

`add_sale()` below:

```
<?php
function add_sale() {
    die("hello");
    $salevehicleid = $_POST['salevehicleid'];
    $saleuserhidid = $_POST['saleuserhidid'];
    $saleusername = $_POST['saleusername'];
    $saleuseremail = $_POST['saleuseremail'];

    $saledate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $letsaleplaced = true;

    $response = array();

    // $saleuserhidid = (int)0;

    // if(is_user_logged_in()){
    //     $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    //     if ($user_id == 0) {
    //         $saleuserhidid = (int)0;
    //     } else {
    //         $saleuserhidid = (int)$user_id;
    //     }
    // }else{
    //     $saleuserhidid = (int)0;
    // }

    // echo $saleuserhidid;

    if($saleuserhidid == (int)0){
        global $wp_query;
        $args = array(
            'post_type'=>'my_custom_sale', 
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'vehicleid',
                    'value' => $salevehicleid,
                    'compare' => '=='
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'usermail',
                    'value' => $saleuseremail,
                    'compare' => '=='
                )
            )
        );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        global $post;

        if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
            $letsaleplaced = false;
        endif;

    }else{
        global $wp_query;
        $args = array(
            'post_type'=>'my_custom_sale', 
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'vehicleid',
                    'value' => $salevehicleid,
                    'compare' => '=='
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'usermail',
                    'value' => $saleuseremail,
                    'compare' => '=='
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'userid',
                    'value' => $saleuserhidid,
                    'compare' => '=='
                )
            )
        );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        global $post;

        if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
            $letsaleplaced = false;
        endif;
    }

    if($letsaleplaced){
        $title = "sale";
        $post_type = 'my_custom_sale';

        $new_sale = array(
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',          
            'post_type'     => $post_type,
            array(
                'public' => true,
                'capability_type' => $post_type,
                'capabilities' => array(
                    'publish_posts' => 'publish_'.$post_type,
                    'edit_posts' => 'edit_'.$post_type.'s',
                    'delete_posts' => 'delete_'.$post_type,
                    'edit_post' => 'edit_'.$post_type,
                    'delete_post' => 'delete_'.$post_type,
                    'read_post' => 'read_'.$post_type,
                    'map_meta_cap' => true
                )
            )
        );

        $pid = wp_insert_post($new_sale);

        add_post_meta($pid, 'userid', $saleuserhidid, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, 'usermail', $saleuseremail, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, 'username', $saleusername, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, 'vehicleid', $salevehicleid, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, 'saledate', $saledate, true);

        //--owner mailing--//
        $owneremailid = "";
        $didsubject = "New Buy Request Added";

        $finalname = "";

        $vehicledata = get_post_meta( $salevehicleid );
        if(!empty($vehicledata)){
            $usersdata = get_user_by( 'id', $vehicledata['customer'][0]);
            $owneremailid = $usersdata->data->user_email;

            $usernamedata = get_userdata($vehicledata['customer'][0]);
            if(!empty($usernamedata)){
                if($usernamedata->first_name != '' && $usernamedata->last_name != ''){
                    $finalname = $usernamedata->first_name." ".$usernamedata->last_name;
                }else{
                    $finalname = $usersdata->data->user_login;
                }
            }else{
                $finalname = $usersdata->data->user_login;
            }
        }
        $carlink = home_url().'/view-vehicle/'.$salevehicleid;
        $content = "<div style='text-align:left;'>Hi, ".ucwords($saleusername)." is interested in buying your <a href='".$carlink."'>vehicle</a>.</div><br> 
            <div style='text-align:left;'>Please contact : Using this email address ".$saleuseremail." to arrange a viewing.</div>";

        $header = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        if(!empty($owneremailid)){
            wp_mail($owneremailid, $didsubject, $content, $header);
        }


        $adminemailid = get_bloginfo('admin_email');
        $didsubject = "New Buy Request Added";

        $carlink = home_url().'/view-vehicle/'.$salevehicleid;
        $admincontent = "<div style='text-align:left;'>".ucwords($saleusername)." place a buy request to ".ucwords($finalname)." <a href='".$carlink."'>vehicle</a> and email address is ".$saleuseremail."</div>";

        $header = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        if(!empty($adminemailid)){
            wp_mail($adminemailid, $didsubject, $admincontent, $header);
        }

        //--admin mailing--//

        $response['status'] = true;
        $response['bidid'] = $pid;
        $response['message'] = 'Buy request added successfully';
    }else{
        $response['status'] = false;
        $response['bidid'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = 'This user can not send buy request.';
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```

Comment: 302 isn't an error. It's means there's an (intentional) redirect. What does the `add_sale()` function do? Please include the code. If it performs a redirect of any kind then that would explain the issue.

Comment: did you try to see if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408334/wordpress-admin-ajax-results-in-error-302-redirect) solves your problem first?

Comment: @Jacob Peattie
https://files.fm/u/w7hmd2nv
here is add_sale function code

Comment: Please include it in the question. And not a link. The actual code.

Comment: yes i did it please check question now

Comment: Is said *not a link*. If the question and answer depend on code that might not be visible in future because you take that file/link down then the question and answer will be useless to the rest of the community if they can't see the relevant code.

Comment: @ Aurovrata

i have applied it.but solution is about to redirect to home page. 
i want result to allow ajax for that users.

Comment: @Jacob Peattie
the code is too long so i have provided in file.

Comment: @dgpoo I think you have not understood the question I linked to.  The user has a similar problem to yours, the admin ajax is accessible for admim users and non-logged in users, just like you pointed out at the top of your question.  So it is possible that non-admin user that are logged are not being allows to access your admin page, and are therefore being redirected (302 response).

Comment: @Aurovrata thanx for gave clarification and attention on that post !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below function works for me by adding `!defined('DOING_AJAX')` in condition.

```
function custom_blockusers_init() {
  if ( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') && ( 
  current_user_can('usercrp') || current_user_can('userpcp') ||  
  current_user_can('subscriber') || current_user_can('contributor') || 
  current_user_can('editor'))) {
    session_destroy();
    wp_logout();
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
   exit;
  }
 }
add_action( 'init', 'custom_blockusers_init' );
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you made my day :-)

I've got a 302 redirect and I looked for "wp_redirect" into my theme code.
Finally, I added && !defined('DOING_AJAX') as well and its works :-)