# Ajax call not working anymore

Tags: ajax, jquery, wp-admin, user-roles, server

I had a few functions I was calling with ajax...basically, everything was working as expected and now it's not. I'm not sure what could be causing this problem.

I have a button on my page like so:

```
<p class='form-submit' method='post'>
    <input id='$message_id' name='message_read' type='button' onclick=hideMessage($message_id) class='submit button mark-as-read' value= 'Mark as read' />
</p>
```

When I click the button, the following ajax code executes from `js/wp-ajax-calls.js`

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

       jQuery(".mark-as-read").click(function () {
          console.log('mark as read ajax called');
         jQuery.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
             data: {
                action: 'mark_message_as_read',
                message_id: this.id
                 }
             success: function (msg) {
                  console.log('action was successful');
                  console.log(msg);
             },
             error: function (errormessage) {
                  console.log(errormessage);
              }
        });
    });
});
```

I see the console message I put in there when I click the button.

In my `functions.php` I have the following function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_mark_message_as_read', 'mark_message_as_read');
function mark_message_as_read() {
    echo "<script>console.log('the message function is called');</script>";
    //do stuff
}
```

I do not see the second console message.

When I check the network tab on my browser, I can see that the ajax requests are generating a 302 response.Interestingly enough, when I log in to my site as the admin user, I get a 200 response and the site behaves exactly as I expect with no issues. I only get the 302 response when I am logged in as a subscriber.

Here are the response headers when I'm logged in as a subscriber:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 31 Oct 2018 05:32:40 GMT
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Location: https://localhost/
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

The 'success' always callback gets called from the original ajax request, no matter who I am logged in as.

Happy to provide more info if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using the REST API instead? Easier URLs, and if you do something wrong it tells you in plain english instead of failing mysteriously. Also you shouldn't return `<script>` tags like that, just return a `true` or `false` to indicate if the message was read, and handle the response in the code that made the request in the first place

Comment: @TomJNowell I just added the `<script>` stuff temporarily to see if the function was getting called. I will remove it once the issue is fixed.

Comment: In your `jQuery.ajax()` call, you're *not* actually doing anything with the AJAX response.. I.e. You don't have a "success" callback — e.g. `jQuery.ajax( {...}).done( function(res){ alert(res); })`

Comment: @SallyCJ I have added some callback functions...I will update my post

Comment: @ellen, I believe your AJAX is actually working; however, if you're actually trying to execute the script in the AJAX response (that's coming from your `mark_message_as_read()` function), then in your `$.ajax()`'s `success` callback, append the `msg` to the DOM and the script would be automatically executed. See [this Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GYbqqv/left?editors=1011) where I got `$('body').append(msg);` in the `success` callback.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank you! The `mark_message_as_read()` function actually updates some data in the database using $wpdb, which I cannot do in javascript. When I actually go look in the database, the data is not modified so I know that that function is not being executed.

Comment: @SallyCJ I have updated my question as well after making some observations

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't really notice the `302` (redirect) status. Can you inspect the AJAX request when you're logged-in as a subscriber, and share the response headers? Or are you able to find the URL where "you" are being redirected to? And try disabling all plugins.. just in case.

Comment: And/or login as a subscriber and mimic a AJAX request by visiting `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=mark_message_as_read` and see if you get redirected.

Comment: @SallyCJ It's very interesting....when I'm logged in as a subscriber and try to visit `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=mark_message_as_read` , I'm redirected to the home page. When I'm logged in as admin I don't get sent to the home page, I can just see the results

Comment: @SallyCJ I've added the response headers: under the 'Response' tab in the inspector it just says 'Failed to load response data'. I can add any other info you want too - thanks for your help!

Comment: Obviously the header `Location` is redirecting the client/browser to your site's home page.. But I'm not sure why is that. Try using a different action name - e.g. `mark_message_as_read2`.. Just to see if it works.

Comment: @SallyCJ Just tried it - `mark_message_as_read2` does the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85152/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-ellen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using this previous post:

[Issue with front-end ajax, getting a 302 redirect when accessing wp-admin/admin-ajax.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/300669/issue-with-front-end-ajax-getting-a-302-redirect-when-accessing-wp-admin-admin)

Basically, I had added an action to prevent subscribers from seeing certain wordpress pages.

```
  function limit_subscriber_access() {
    $redirect = home_url( '/' );
    if ( ! ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) || current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ))
        exit( wp_redirect( $redirect ) );
}
```

This was causing the 302 redirect and preventing the $wpdb related code from executing. Here is what I added:

```
  function limit_subscriber_access() {
    $redirect = home_url( '/' );
    if ( ! ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) || current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        exit( wp_redirect( $redirect ) );
}
```

I tested and it seems to be working how I wanted.

Thanks to everybody who helped me try to figure it out!